# Set single page in subsite to different master page in master site

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, sub-site

I have created a new Site Master page in my site. I want to assign the master page to just one single sub-site page. I've attempted to change the "MasterPageFile" but was unsuccessful (I know this is set as a referential). The Site Master Page is in both my subsite and master site's master page's folder. Is there a specific URL path to use to change the MasterPageFile at runtime?

Comment: the correct approach is to use MasterPageFile. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I attempted to use '~masterurl/newmaster.master' which is the name of the .master page in both the subsite master pages and parent site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer your master page in different ways as shown below:

1. Site Collection-Relative Master Page:
   ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master
2. Site-Relative Master Page: ~site/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master
3. Relative path are based on where the page resides:
   "../_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master"

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my question. I was trying to edit a site page instead of a publishing page.